# Checking whether a string is present in a bunch of other strings by row and expand columns to sign this test

Tags: r

I would like to have a data frame marked if a string from a vector of strings is present or not in a given column of a data frame by row. The following is a toy data and next is how I would like the outcome to be. It can go ok with loops, but if possible, I'd like to not use loop, once this data is about 3 million rows.

```
  mydata <- structure(list(X7 = c("00019", "00019", "00019", "00019", "00035", "00035"), X17 = c("A / BG / C / D / E", "E / D", "B / F", "B / C", "A / BE / G / F", "AB / G" ), n = c(10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L)), .Names = c("X7", "X17", "n"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

.

```
> mydata
     X7                X17  n
1 00019 A / BG / C / D / E 10
2 00019              E / D  4
3 00019              B / F  4
4 00019              B / C  4
5 00035     A / BE / G / F  8
6 00035             AB / G  4
```

In the outcome data the columns can go until the last letter of alphabet, here I just print a subset from it.

```
 > outcome
         X7               X17   n A B C D E F G
    1 00019 A / BG / C / D / E  10 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
    2 00019              E / D   4 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    3 00019              B / F   4 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
    4 00019              B / C   4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
    5 00035     A / BE / G / F   8 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
    6 00035             AB / G   4 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method using `sapply` and `grepl`:

```
outcome2 <- cbind(mydata, sapply(LETTERS[1:7], function(i) as.integer(grepl(i, mydata$X17))))
```

`sapply` loops through the letters A-G created by `LETTERS[1:7]`. `grepl` checks if each letter is present in a row of `mydata$X17` and is transformed from a logical (TRUE / FALSE) to a binary integer (0 /1) with `as.integer`.

```
# test that the outcomes are the same
identical(outcome, outcome2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This approach is really powerful. But I had to change the example to conforme more to the real data. I've some situations that two or more characters go together, so when I apply your solution I will get, for instance in the last row, a mark in the column A, B, and G, but what I need is a mark only for G, since AB is different of A or B.

Comment: This problem can be solved by using `paste(LETTERS,"$", sep="")`, though in the real data I'm getting the following error message: `Error: cannot convert object to a data frame`

Comment: I've found the likely issue, the data frame is a "grouped_df" not a simple tbl.